# Density overlap of orthogonal wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction

Intuitively, I suspect that orthogonal wavefunctions don't have much overlap in their densities. For example, in separable approximations of many-body fermions like Hartree-Fock, the wavefunctions of each fermion are orthogonal, and it feels intuitively right that fermions would prefer not to have much overlap in their positions/densities.

Suppose we have orthonormal wavefunctions $\phi_n(x)$, such that:
$$ \int \phi^*_n(x)\phi_m(x)dx=\delta_{nm} $$
Can we say anything useful about whether the density overlap:
$$\int\left|\phi_n(x)\right|^2\left|\phi_m(x)\right|^2dx$$
is small when $n\neq m$? I played around with some inequalities, but all I could show was that:
$$ \int \phi^*_n(x)\phi_m(x)dx\leq \int\left|\phi_n(x)\right|^2\left|\phi_m(x)\right|^2dx$$
which isn't very useful, since we just have that a zero quantity is less than an obviously nonzero positive quantity. I considered perhaps that orthogonal wavefunctions locally minimize the density overlap, and thought about using Lagrange multipliers, but I had difficulty with that approach too.

Comment: Using Cauchy-Schwartz you can bound the density overlap integral from above, just using the fact that the basis functions are unit-normalized. But that's not a very interesting result.

Comment: Small compared with what? Your density overlap isn’t a dimensionless number; it has dimensions of inverse length.

Comment: Your intuition is wrong. It is perfectly possible to have orthogonal wavefunctions with full overlap in their densities.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the diversity in the sets of orthogonal functions, one cannot make any statements about the overlap of the intensities (or densities) of two mutually orthogonal functions. It suffice to illustrate this by examples.

As a first example, consider two mutually orthogonal plane waves: $\phi_{1,2}=\exp(i\mathbf{k}_{1,2}\cdot\mathbf{x})$, for different wave vectors $\mathbf{k}_1$ and $\mathbf{k}_2$. Their intensities are $|\phi_{1,2}|^2=1$. So they overlap everywhere.

As a second example, consider the hat-function:
$$ h(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & {\rm for} & |x|<1 \\ 
0 & {\rm for} & |x|\geq 1 \end{array} \right. $$
Shifted versions of this function are orthogonal provided that the relative shifts are larger than 1. The intensities of two such functions won't have any overlap.

Hopefully these two examples illustrate that one cannot say much about the overlap of the intensities of orthogonal functions.

Comment: These counterexamples aren't actually in $L^2$, though. Neither of them are normalised. I think such a result is possible if we consider only physical/normalised wavefunctions.

Comment: @user502382 Work on an interval with periodic boundary conditions, then.